# How to add blade pitch angle animation to the propeller?

Tags: modeling, animation

I can spin the blades but I do not know how I can add [Blade Pitch Angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_pitch) alteration to the propellers. To animate the pitch angle increase of the blades by separating them and assigning rotation axis separately and rotate seems to be complicated and time consuming. Also I do not know if that will work or not. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "blade pitch angle alteration"?

Comment: I want to change pitch angle of the blades with time like low pitch to feather position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way:

- A blade-object, all selected in Edit mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> *Hook*ed to a 'Pitch Control' Empty
- Further modified to a radial *Array*, using a rotated 'Object Offset' Empty.
- Both Empties and the blade parented to a rotating element (here, the nose-cone).
- The nose-cone parented to the aircraft, to pick up its roll, pitch, and yaw.

[image]

Then the propeller can be spun by rotating the nose-cone, and the blade-pitch can be controlled with the hook.. rotating the blade's mesh while leaving the blade-object in place, so the offset-array isn't messed up.

Maybe a bit lazy?

Another way would be to instance the blades so they are objects in their own right, rotate them into place in Object Mode, and parent as before.

Then you could, say, make one of the blades a controller, and give the others a local *Copy Rotation* constraint, aimed at the controller.

That version is included in the .blend:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, answer is very clear, I will try this methods.